# Scroll bar slider behavior

Tags: c, scroll, widget, scrollbar

I am implementing a scrolled window control.
I need to draw simple scrollbar sliders for this purpose.

Usually, sliders shrink as the content grows, but I am unable to understand how.
What is the relation/ratio formula? I've made several google tries to find out, but I didn't.

Does it have a minimum size it can go or it is just really hard to shrink it that far due to exponential shrinking behavior? We are talking simple generic scrollbars. What would be the proper way to implement the proper slider dynamic sizing?

Comment: Please be so kind to leave a comment on what I could change. What's wrong with the question - why is it not receiving enough attention. For now, I assume it is boring.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously this question is so dumb that nobody would bother answering.
I used to make complex hacks but now the simplest logic just slipped away across my mind.

The horizontal scroll bar slider width is the portion of the content (child) width.

```
(width / content) * width

width * width / content
```